# Arrayformula with in column operations

Tags: google-sheets

I'm usign `ARRAYFORMULA` like this in my `C1` cell:

```
=arrayformula(IF(row(A:A)=1; "C label"; (A:A)/(B:B)))
```

in my top cell and everything works as expected.

```
|   A   |   B   |   C label   |
|-----------------------------|
|  10   |   5   |      2      |
|   8   |   4   |      2      |
|   4   |   2   |      2      |
|  16   |   2   |      8      |
```

Now I need something like this:

```
|   A   |   B   |
|---------------|
|  100  |  100  |
|  200  |  140  |
|  340  |  160  |
|  500  |       |
```

that is: `B2 = A3-A2, B3 = A4-A3` and so on...

How to do it automagically with `arrayformula`? I can't use B:B or A:A like operations in row, I can't use 1:1 or 2:2, how to?

I'm using arrayformula because of automagically calulating when adding new lines.

Answer (score 1):

## Formula

```
=ArrayFormula(Array_constrain(A2:A-A:A,COUNT(A:A)-1,1))
```

## Explanation

Use Array_constrain to avoid filling the last row and filling up blank rows.