# Split text in Google Sheets with a delimiter which contains spaces

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrays

I have a column (A) in Google Sheets where each row contains the following string:

"TEXT **on** MORE_TEXT" or, for more specific example "occurred on December 17, 2020".  The "MORE_TEXT" part can be any of the 12 months.

I need to split it so that the "December 17, 2020" is in a separate column and my desired delimiter is " on ", which is a space character followed by the word "on" and then another space.

But when I use `=SPLIT(A:A," on ")` it ignores the spaces around "on" and I have no other ideas.

I am sure I am about to learn something simple but effective and am looking forward to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve the result you are looking. Here is one of the oldies, using RIGHT, LEN and FIND

```
=ArrayFormula(RIGHT(A:A,LEN(A:A) - FIND(" on ",A:A) - 3)
```

Another way, in this case using SPLIT, SUBSTITUTE and INDEX

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A:A," on ","|"),"|"),1,2))
```

One way using regular expressions

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A," on (.+)"))
```

P.S. The simplest way to avoid having errors for blanks cells below the las row having a value on A, delete all the bottom blank rows.

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you very much!

I also use the IF(LEN) code to keep the blank rows empty in array formulas, so I modified your suggestion as below

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A:A)>0,RIGHT(A:A,LEN(A:A) - FIND(" on ",A:A) - 3),""))`

Thank you again!

Comment: Bear in mind that returning `""` still returning setting a value for all the blank cells in Column A. This might not be a problem is you keep your spreadsheet simple and your sheet with few blank rows.

Comment: @M2Z by the way, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Sometimes deleting multiple blank rows becomes time-consuming but I am happy to create a different question to find out how to avoid adding `""` to keep the "false" and "error" values out.

Also, I upvoted your answer but it won't show up as I am a newbie here and the "Accept" checkmark finally showed up after I reinstalled 2 browsers (unrelated issues) so I finally did that too

Comment: @M2Z Thanks. Here is a link to question with an answer showing the use of ARRAY_CONSTRAIN together with COUNTIF https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/99783/88163